# Angular debounce with mask on input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, debouncing, input-mask, angular-controlvalueaccessor

There is an HTML `<input/>` (`ReactiveFormsModule`) and I would like to have two (independent) features:

- debounced input
- input with a mask

I would like to apply the *Single Responsibility* pattern:

- so I have implemented [appDebounceInput](https://github.com/felikf/angular-pohovor/blob/slider/src/shared/debounce-input-component.directive.ts) (using ControlValueAccessor/CVA)
- used a library for the mask - [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

[app.component.html](https://github.com/felikf/angular-pohovor/blob/slider/src/app/app.component.html):

```html
<input type="text"
       [formControl]="formControl"
       appDebounceInput                <!-- CVA1 -->
       mask="separator.0"              <!-- CVA2 -->
/>
```

But this causes a problem, because there are two CVAs now (first from `appDebounceInput`, second from `mask`).

```
Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute
```

(Yes, I know, Angular can't have two CVAs on single input.)

I would like to keep both features separated and use them independently or combined.

(And I do not want to move the debounce time logic in consuming component:  `this.formGroup.get('money').valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500))` - I want to update the `formGroup` after debounce time.)

One option would be to create an extra component and hide the `input` with the mask (one CVA) in this component and implement debounce on top - but this approach would hide the native HTML (causing some other problems, such as native input features will be hidden).

I am looking for a better approach how to solve this issue:

- Single Responsibility for features
- have both features independent
- and have the possibility to use them combined

Any ideas? :)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/felikf/angular-pohovor/tree/slider).

Comment: The StackBlitz will not run for me.  It just says "*Compiling application & starting dev server…*" :-\

Comment: What if you move one of the decorators (e.g debounce) out from template and decorate a function instead e.g on `(input)` https://stackblitz.com/edit/debouce-decorator-1kjv7j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdebouce.decorator.ts

Comment: @Joosep.P I think your solution is not compatible with Reactive Forms :(